# Play java Request extension

Tags: java, playframework-2.2, request-headers, global-object

Im catching all requests with OnRequest function ( in my global object).

I want to add some information to my request. Im trying to extend the Request class with no success so far...

If anyone have any idea on how to add info to every Request im catching without extending this class it would be great, and also if anyone can help with how do i extend it.

P.S.
Everything is written in java, but im open to scala ideas . My play version is 2.2.1.

Thanks!